# Video player for web, mobile and desktop applications in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

There is this Flutter plugin for playing videos on iOS & Android [(Video Plugin)](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player)

However, I also want to embed a video player into my web and desktop applications.

So I dont understand how Flutter is going this way of supporting plugins for different platforms. Because if you have a look at the video plugin it makes use of the **AVPlayer on iOS** and **ExoPlayer on Android**, but these are not then supported for web and desktop applications.

**My Questions:**
Why isn't the community writing a Flutter plugin for videos which is independent of it's underlying platform? Or isn't it possible? Why do we have to rely so much on Android & iOS especially if Flutter will be more and more platform independent in the future? Isn't it possible to write the source code for making videos working on different platforms solely with the Dart language & Flutter framework?

**Is there currently a way to embed a video player for web and desktop applications?**

Answer (score 6):

You can use [dart_vlc](https://github.com/alexmercerind/dart_vlc) to add video playback to your Flutter desktop application.

It currently supports Windows & Linux, we are working on adding macOS support actively.

The library is rather easier to use aswell,

```dart
Player player = Player(id: 0);
player.open(
  Playlist(
    medias: [
      Media.file(File('C:/music.mp3')),
      Media.file(File('C:/audio.mp3')),
      Media.network('https://www.example.com/music.aac'),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Thanks. Checkout project README for more examples and documentation.

Comment: Does it require any installation for Windows? Does it require VLC to be pre-installed?

Comment: @OliverDixon, no it doesn't need to be installed on Windows. On Linux, apps depend on distro specific packages, so kinda "yes", otherwise you could use Snapcraft or Flatpak to bundle your app together with shared libraries.

Comment: Do don't deploy Linux, got it 

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `WebView` by `flutter_webview_plugin` package. It can take advantage of the built-in video decoders/players in any Operating Systems as they're pre-loaded as web content.

Edit: This is because not many Video Plugins are to be found for the Desktop and Web Platforms yet (At least by me)

Comment: ```flutter_webview_plugin``` only works for iOS and Android as of today.

Answer (score 0):

The `video_player` along with the `video_player_web` plugins work for web, android and ios. But I have not tested them on a desktop.